# Pandas groupby adding additional number when as_index=True

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
df.to_dict()
Out[24]: 
{'Col1': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'B'},
 'Col2': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'b', 4: 'c'},
 'Col3': {0: 42, 1: 28, 2: 56, 3: 62, 4: 48}}
```

I am trying the following:

```
df2 = df.sort_values('Col3', ascending=False).groupby(['Col1', 'Col2'], as_index=True).apply(lambda x: x.head(1))
```

However, the index of `df2` gets added an additional index variable to show the following:

```
df2.index
Out[26]: 
MultiIndex([('A', 'a', 0),
            ('B', 'b', 3),
            ('B', 'c', 4)],
           names=['Col1', 'Col2', None])
```

I need to get the multiindex only with `Col1` and `Col2` in `df2`. I am not sure how to resolve the above.

My expected output should be:

```
df2.index
Out[26]: 
MultiIndex([('A', 'a'),
            ('B', 'b'),
            ('B', 'c')],
           names=['Col1', 'Col2'])
```

Edit:

I need to use the `head()` method as I have another scenario where `head(4)` will be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `first`

```
df.sort_values('Col3', ascending=False).groupby(['Col1', 'Col2'], as_index=True).first()
```

Fix your code `reset_index(level=2,drop=True)`

```
df2 = df.sort_values('Col3', ascending=False).groupby(['Col1', 'Col2'], as_index=True).apply(lambda x: x.head(1)).reset_index(level=2,drop=True)
```